# Audio recording is not working in apple devices in next js app

Tags: html, typescript, next.js, audio, audio-recording

After recording, User is unable to play recorded audio. It is showing "Error" in audio player. User is also allowing recording permission. Please see error message in attached screenshot.

Steps to reproduce:

1. open application in safari in mac device
2. click on "Audio" button
3. record something
4. click on "Stop recording" button
5. Error will be displayed in audio control and dev tools console

I am using opensource github repo for audio recording in next js application. Functionality is workin fine in browser in windows machine. But, this functionality is not working in apple device i.e. mac book and iphone's browser.

Github repo: https://github.com/thereis/poc-media-recorder

I also tried to implement audio recording functionality using vmsg npm package.but it has some version issue.

sandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/2hn33h

Error screenshot:
[image]